# Is Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS getting neglected by Canonical?

Tags: ubuntu, python, openssl

I'm doing some clean installs and am faced with the issue that OpenSSL is at version `1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014` (yay, heartbleed!), and Python at 2.7.6.

I'm having a really hard time upping OpenSSL to the latest **1.0.1p** and Python **2.7.10**, have been spending at least 8 hours compiling / modifying and am still not able to get Python 2.7.10 to use OpenSSL 1.0.1p

That's wrong with you guys? This is the default Ubuntu distro on AWS offered since pre heartbleed and whatever came since then...

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You are, indeed missing something.  14.04**LTS**  is a Long Term Stable Release, which means that, like Redhat over Fedora, it values stability and compatibility over being cutting edge.

In fact, if you have done an apt-get update; apt-get upgrade, the version of OpenSSL you are running will NOT be vulnerable to heartbleed even though its 1.0.1f - Ubuntu simply patched the version rather then create a new version.   You can see [the evidence](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449184/how-to-upgrade-openssl-1-0-1f-on-ubuntu-server-14-04) here.

I see you have opened a seperate question about your Python issue.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was aware of https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS . My issue is that whe I run a `openssl s_client -connect test.server.ip:443 -tlsextdebug 2>&1 | grep 'server extension "heartbeat" (id=15)' || echo safe` I'm not getting a "safe" but a *TLS server extension "heartbeat" (id=15), len=1*. This is when I serve https directly from Python as well as when I reverse-proxy it through nginx (both installed via apt-get). So apparently Python 2.7.6 and nginx/1.4.6 are not using a patched OpenSSL library. Are both statically linking to an old version?